# What does format=None do in Django rest full API

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

Recently when I read Django rest full API document I faced this code :

```
    def get(self, request, format=None):
    """Return a list of APIView features."""

    an_apiview = [
        'Uses HTTP methods as function (get, post, patch, put, delete).',
        'It is similar to a traditional Django view.',
        'Gives you most control over you logic.',
        'Its mapped manually to URLs.'
    ]

    return Response({'message': 'Hello!', 'an_apiview': an_apiview})
```

this code is work fine but I look for `format=None` and I cant find out what does it do. is any body know what is it and why its important to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The django rest framework (drf) documentation explains it [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/).

The gist of it is that when you want to support multiple file types in your response, drf provides a shortcut to support this, but requires you to include 'format' as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

format() is a built-in function in Python that converts a value into the required format. Here format is none indicate so specified format is required allow all.

Comment: This question is not about the `format()` builtin function.